# use split to add fields to a list python

Tags: python, list, loops, split

I am doing a class assignment that asks me to add a list of username/passwords to a list in python. I have some code that isn't working and I am stuck. What I want is to have one list for usernames and one list for passwords.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
for Line in open(psw):
    fields = Line.split(":")

print (fields)
```

Here is the text file that I am trying to split.

```
administrator:admin

administrator:password

admin:12345

admin:1234

root:root

root:password

root:toor
```

Comment: What is not working at the moment?

Comment: `fields` is a tuple where `fields[0]` is the username and `fields[1]` is the password. Make two empty lists and append things to the back of them. You can also be clever and use `zip()`.

Comment: @Blender Could you give an example of zip()?

Comment: @user2363217: `zip(*[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]) == [(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]`.

Comment: @Blender I am still confused... Could you give an example that I could apply to this project?

Comment: @user2363217: `usernames, passwords = zip(*(line.split(':') for line in file_handle))`.

Comment: @Blender I still cannot get zip to work. Here is the code I have: `usernames, passwords = zip(*(line.split(':') for line in psw))` and I get an error saying that it needs more than 1 argument to unpack.

Answer (score 0):

There is not point of splitting the pair into 2 lists. If you keep them separate, operations like sort are much more difficult.

You probably want the get a list of all users, without the password. For this you can use a list comprehension:

First we need to get the actual user_pass_list. Your loop does the job already, we only need an append call.

```
user_pass_list = []

for Line in open(psw):
    fields = Line.split(":")
    user_pass_list.append(fields)

print (user_pass_list)
```

Now to get a list of all users:

```
users = (x[0] for x in user_pass_list)
```

You can read more about list comprehensions in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: How would I remove the \n from the output?

Comment: @user2363217 string.strip(char)

Answer (score 0):

It is great to use dictionaries in this case. 
For example,

```
user_pass_comb = {}
user_pass_comb['admin'] = "root"
user_pass_comb['student'] = "myroot"
```

and so on...

*now you can run an iterator or index the password directly and it will save your running time too.*

for getting all passwords you can do something like this.

```
for i in range(user_pass_comb):
   print user_pass_comb[i]
```